# Get the value from a JTextField & re-write it into an existing variable

Tags: java, swing, variables, jtextfield

Get the value from a JTextField & re-write it into an existing variable.

example:

```
public class variables{

     String var = "hi";

  public static void main(String[]args){

  //do sth    

  }

}
```

then interface reads the value from the main class & change the value from a JTextField

```
private void changeVariableActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               


  variables.var = txtField.getText();

  //then into textfield we write bye  & variables.var takes the value of bye

  //variables.var = "bye"

}
```

I want to change the Value of var with the action perform

Comment: add some information about the notice of updating. you mention get the value, but what action causes the prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ActionLister` to the `JTextField` and each time you change the value assign it to you variable.

you could do something like this:

```
txtField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        variables.var = txtField.getText();

     }
 });
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't get what do you mean ?

Comment: in netbeas u just right click to the jtext field or combo etc & u chose the action perform or whatever action u want.
My question is, if there's a way to do it like that.

Comment: Yes, just right click and on `txtfield` and add action listener. then put `variables.var = txtField.getText();` inside the `actionPerformed` method.